# How do I plot several y-values to 1 x-value?

Tags: plotting, data

I want to plot a several list of varying size to distinct values.

For example, consider I had

```
a={1,2,3} 
b={4,5,6,7}
c={0,1}
```

and I wanted to plot all values of a to an x=value of 1, all b values to an x-value of 2, all c values to an x-value of 3. How would I do this?

Comment: `ListPlot[{a, b, c}]` will do the job

Comment: @mgamer You have misread the question.

Comment: Edmund: Uuups you are right, so I have to give a different solution than your `MapIndexed` .... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) with a nested pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Function[{value, index}, {First@index, #} & /@ value]]@{a, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6, 7};
c = {0, 1};
d = {1, a[[#]]} & /@ {1, 2, 3};
e = {2, b[[#]]} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4};
f = {3, c[[#]]} & /@ {1, 2};
ListPlot[{d, e, f}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

O.K. I misread the question, sorry for that. So here another version to do the job:

```
x = {1, 2, 3}; a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6, 7};
c = {0, 1};
```

Then

```
values = {a, b, c};
```

and now making the tuples (just to present a solution without `MapIndexed`, since Edmund picked this option ;-) )

```
tab = Table[Thread[List[x[[i]], values[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length@values}]
```

then

```
ListPlot[Flatten[tab, 1]]
```

yields:

[image]