# Plotting a table with one x-value and multiple y-values

Tags: plotting

I have a table which reads

```
d1={{-3., {0, 0, -0.9729028016, 0.9729028016, -0.6213440060, 0.6213440060, -0.7466742950, 0.7466742950}}, {-1.15, {-0.8181534086, 0.8181534086, -0.9903801932, 0.9903801932, -0.8872823355, 0.8872823355, -0.9190670645, 0.9190670645}}, {0.7, {-0.9367496998, 0.9367496998, -0.9958159209, 0.9958159209, -0.9565982873, 0.9565982873, -0.9675278482, 0.9675278482}}, {2.55, {0, 0, -0.9757575014, 0.9757575014, -0.6569920699, 0.6569920699, -0.7720102395, 0.7720102395}}}
```

For plotting this data, I have used

```
ListPlot[Transpose@d1, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

But the output is empty. I have checked other threads like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130677/how-do-i-plot-several-y-values-to-1-x-value) but the answers didn't resolve my issue. Do you have a suggestion on how to plot this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to construct points.

```
ListPlot[Thread /@ d1]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!